# How to migrate from sha256 encryption to bcrypt for PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

> For Login :

```
$rows       = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$us_id      = $rows['id'];
$us_pass    = $rows['password'];
$us_salt    = $rows['password_salt'];
$status     = $rows['attempt'];
$saltedPass = hash('sha256', "{$password}{$this->passwordSalt}{$us_salt}");
```

> For Register :

```
$randomSalt = $this->rand_string(20);
$saltedPass = hash('sha256', "{$password}{$this->passwordSalt}{$randomSalt}");
```

**How can this sha256 encryption method be converted to bcrypt?**

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: Actually , I have used bcrypt in my mobile application. Hence I want to change my web application's encryption as I am sharing the database. How could that help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Password Hashing Using bcrypt**

If you are using PHP 5.5 or later, you can use the built-in [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function with the `$algo` parameter set to `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` to create bcrypt hashes. You can use this as so:

```
$options = array('cost' => 11, 'salt' => 'my_salt');
$hash = password_hash("my_secret_password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

**Migration**

It's not possible to do a bulk migration from sha256 to bcrypt because you need the original plaintext data (password) which isn't available.

Typically, sites do a staged conversion where you convert users as they perform successful logins. For example:

1. create a field in your database for password has type, sha256 or bcrypt
2. upon login, verify the password using the type in the database
3. if sha256 and successful, create a new bcrypt entry using the entered password, store that and update the password type to bcrypt. On the next login, bcrypt will now be used for verification.

Comment: I just wanted to change those above lines . Those are the only two lines which are sha256 . So is there any way that I can change those lines?

Comment: If you are on PHP 5.5 or later, you can use the `password_hash()` function with the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` option. I've added this to the answer above. Are you on PHP 5.5 or later?

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP 5.5.

Comment: You should not be generating your own salt. Let `password_hash()` generate the salt for you. It uses a CSPRNG.