# Can a bcrypt hashed password be converted to SHA2?

Tags: php

I have two applications that use different ways to hash the users password. I want to syncronize these applications so that the user is allowed to login with the same user credentials.

Is it possible to convert a bcrypt password to SHA2?

Comment: Sure, just make them enter the password again and re-hash that password with SHA2.

Comment: No, but you can syncronize on user login. I would strongly suggest you use Bcrypt though, makes no sense downgrading to sha2

Comment: why not just let them update their password instead using the same algo? Since you can't get the original password from the hashed version; I'd do that instead; if you have control over it that is.

Comment: use if else to find the application and use hashing method according to the application

Comment: This being a somewhat relevant Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/30940324/1415724 where the accepted answer states: *"It's not possible to do a bulk migration from sha256 to bcrypt because you need the original plaintext data (password) which isn't available."* (which is what I said in an earlier comment). This also applies to your wanting to go from bcrypt to sha2; why? I don't know. What I suggest you do is, and if you have control over both, is to use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on both applications or the compatibility pack.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: `bcrypt` is a secure password hashing method, SHA2 is not, see above comment. Using insecure password methods puts the users at risk, please do not do that. Also there is no SHA2 hashing algorithm, SHA2 is a set of cryptographic hash functions.

Answer (score -1):

Bcrypt and SHA-256 is a one-way hashing algorithm, you can't decrypt hashes (without brute-forcing). You **cannot** do a bulk password change. However, it is still possible to convert your database from one algorithm to another. Here's how:

1. Each time a user is logged into your website, compare if the supplied password matches the hash saved in your database.
2. If there is a match, then take the supplied password which would probably be in $_POST['password'] and then hash it to your destination algorithm like `hash('mypassword', 'mypassword');`

That's the only way you would be able to convert those hashed password.

In previous version of WordPress, they used to store passwords as hashed MD5. They have now introduced a new password algorithm and that how it works to convert old MD5 password hashes when you upgrade.

Comment: Bcrypt and SHA2 are not equivalent hashing algorithms, Bcrypt is a computationally intensive method designed for password hashing, SHA2 (whatever that is) is not suitable for password hashing.

Comment: Whether Bcrypt is extensive or not is out of subject based on the OP Question. And it is of course not equivalent hashing algorithm else it would have the same name. Not sure why you are stating the obvious. What I am missing?

Comment: The question is about password hashing. Do you really want to help put the OP's users at risk with an insecure password hashing method?